# How do I log which tests failed and which tests succeeded with NUnit by logging the test name?

Tags: nunit

How do I log which tests failed and which tests succeeded with NUnit? I want to be able to write all of the NUnit output to a file after all of the tests run.

Answer (score 2):

```
nunit-console nunit.tests.dll /out:TestResult.txt
```

As taken from the NUnit manual, http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.4.